# Converting multi-dimensional array to a single HTML-like array?

Tags: php, arrays

What is the fastest or most convenient possible way to convert a multi-dimensional array to a single HTML-like array (the method that is used to set the `name` attribute in HTML forms)? For example,

```
$ar = [
    'x' => ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3],
    'y' => ['yy' => ['yyy' => 3]],
    'z' => 3333,
    'm' => [1, 2],
];
```

should be converted to:

```
  $ar = [
        'x[a]' => 1,
        'x[b]' => 2,
        'x[c]' => 3,
        'y[yy][yyy]' => 3,
        'z' => 3333,
        'm[0]' => 1,
        'm[1]' => 2,
    ];
```

Here is my first try:

```
$ar = [
    'x' => ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3],
    'y' => ['yy' => ['yyy' => '3']],
    'z' => 3333,
    'm' => [1, 'x']
];

function convert($key, $value, &$new)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            convert($key."[$k]", $v, $new);
        }
        else {
            $new[$key."[$k]"] = $v;
        }
    }
}
$r = [];
convert(null, $ar, $r);
print_r($r);;
```

Comment: It has to be the fastest possible?

Comment: HTML-like array is **JavaScript** array?

Comment: @PHPst any method will almost have the same cost, you need to go through array content and restructure it.

Comment: Recursive function with `foreach`  is simple, but speed -- I don't know! Are there any other "good" ways to do it? `array_keys()`

Comment: @PHPst It looks like you actually mean the method used for the `name` attribute. You want something like `<input name="y[yy][yyy]" value="3">`, right?

Comment: If you need help please collaborate.

Comment: Looks like you need to write a recursive function that appends the key to the name for each level in the array. Have you tried writing anything yourself? We're not a free programming service, we're here to help you fix problems in your code.

Comment: @Barmar " It looks like you a .… " yes, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about speed, but this is a convenient way to do the trick:

```
$ar = convert_array( $ar );

function convert_array( $a, $key = '' ) {
    static $arr = array();
    foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
        $key_name = $key == '' ? $k : $key . '[' . $k . ']';
        if ( is_array( $v) ) {
            convert_array( $v, $key_name );
        } else {
            $arr[$key_name] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hasse, I accept your question for now. I am not sure if it's possible to do that not-recursively.